# how to write a shell script to take password automattically after the execution of command

Tags: linux, script, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/SUNWdsee/ds6/bin
./dsconf show-repl-agmt-status -e suffix Hostname:389
```

Above is my script. After the execution of the last line it will prompt for password in screen.

I need to know how can we automatically populate password after the command execution (`./dsconf show-repl-agmt-status -e suffix Hostname:389`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving that as input

```
echo "Any#PasSwD" > .passwd.txt
./dsconf show-repl-agmt-status -e suffix Hostname:389 < .passwd.txt
```

If the above works, you can even try the below

```
./dsconf show-repl-agmt-status -e suffix Hostname:389 | echo "Any#PasSwD"
```